# c# webapplication call webservice to writefile on server

Tags: javascript, c#, web-applications, file-io

The first two functions works well but the third one with some error unclear. Here is all the codes and could you help me how to complete the last function.

code in WebService1.asmx

```
using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Web.Services;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorldFun1()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorldFun2(string str)
        {
            return "Hello World,"+str;
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public string Write_to_File(string str)
        {
            StreamWriter _testData = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/output.txt"), true);
            _testData.WriteLine(str); // Write the file.
            _testData.Flush();
            _testData.Close(); // Close the instance of StreamWriter.
            _testData.Dispose(); // Dispose from memory. 
            return str;
        }

    }
}
```

code in Default.aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>WebService</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function func1()
        {        
        WebApplication1.WebService1.HelloWorldFun1(onSuccess,onFail,'Span1');
        }
        function func2()
        {
        var txt=document.getElementById('Text1').value;
        WebApplication1.WebService1.HelloWorldFun2(txt,onSuccess,onFail,'Span2');
        }
        function write()
        {
        var txt = document.getElementById("Span1").innerHTML;
        WebApplication1.WebService1.Write_to_File("kkkkkkkkkk",onSuccess,onFail,'Span3');
        }
        function onSuccess(value,context)
        {
        document.getElementById(context).innerHTML=value;
        }
        function onFail(value)
        {
        alert(value);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebService1.asmx"  />
    </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button"  onclick="func1()" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="Span1"></span>
    <hr />
    <input id="Text1" type="text" /><input id="Button2" type="button" value="button"  onclick="func2()" /><span id="Span2"></span>
    </form> 
    <input id = "WTF" type = "button" value = "write" onclick ="write()"/><span id="Span3"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its seems to be write permission issue. please grant the write permission and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have know the reason. There should be some defined function named "write()". I just change the name "write()" to "write_to()" and then it works well. Thanks for your answers, Vitali Kaspler.

Answer (score 0):

1) What is the error? (Runtime Exception \ Stack Trace  or its a compilation error? )

2) _testData.Close(); // Close the instance of StreamWriter.
   _testData.Dispose(); // Dispose from memory.

Calling to Close() is enough (this is similar to Dispose, so you are disposing twice... Not an error, but still nice to know.)

Comment: I think it should be a runtime exception and once I click the button "write", the page would give no response even I click other buttons. And I have tried the 2) you gave, but it did not work. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The web service seems to be ok, and it works (otherwise you would get an exception).
The Default.aspx seems to have a problem.

I'd recommend to use JQuery to call the Web Service.

Comment: The problem has been solved. JQuery should be very useful and I am glad to learn it sometime. Thank you again.